# Dynamic opacity in html

Tags: html

I have a variable with value in range of 0-1, and I want to determine opacity of element according to it. I know there is a way to do it with css, but I want to do it in html.
This is my html code:

```
<td align=center bgcolor=(255,0,0)>
```

Comment: Could you please share your CSS and HTML code?

Comment: You can't. Without CSS your HTML is nothing more than text.

Comment: HTML doesn't do styles...? You have to do it with CSS. Even inline styles in HTML documents are CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this only with HTML. You will need a CSS rule or Javascript code to set the CSS value. For example:

```
.foo {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

and set `class="foo"` for the tag. If you need to set the opacity using Javascript, then you can do something like this

```
var myOpacityValue = 0.5;
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.opacity = myOpacityValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLElement.style

Refer [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```js
function myFunction() {
var opacity = document.getElementById("opacity").value;
document.getElementById("container").style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

```css
body{
background-color: #ccc;
}
#container{
height:50px;
width:100px;
background-color:#003F87;
color:#000;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Enter the opacity value</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
<input type=number id="opacity" step="0.01" min="0" max="1">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>
```